# pass parameters through serivals pages

Tags: jsp

first,thanks for everyone taking time reading this...
for example,like a product line,each page will create some params,
and the current page may need to user the params created in the previous page..
I am not sure how to pass params through these pages,
maybe i need to say ,don't know choose which way.
we can use cookie、session、javabean and maybe others
using the cookie may results in some mistakes because of it's expires,
and using the session,i dont't know whether it would bring pressure to the server..
anyone can give me some suggestions?

---

in the end,sorry for my english...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use forms to do this..

In your first page

create a form with an action and pass the parameters you need to pass within this form.Only params passed within the input tags will get passed to the action page..Remember to put a name variable in the input field.
For example

```
<form action="hello.jsp" method="post">
<input type="text" name="hello"/>
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

(The action preferably is a servelet,just for an example I am showing you as a JSP)

At the action page request
**hello.jsp**

you can get the text by calling `request.getParameter("hello");`

You can refer this links

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_form_processing.htm
http://www.iforerunner.com/jsp/JSP_SimpleForm.html

Comment: Eh..maybe you have misunderstood my question,i know the form can do this,but i think this way is just usable when passing params in two pages,it may be a bad way pass params in several pages.. is it right?

Comment: you mean u want to use these params throughout your web project?

Comment: yes, but not the whole project, just a few. i am not sure which way way is better..(0.0 by the way , thank you)